Tailwind element aligment inside grid
How can I align first element of a two columns grid to the left and the second element to the right?
+------------------------------------------+
| [Button1]                      [Button2] |
+------------------------------------------+

It doesn't necessarily have to be a grid; it could be a different alignment method, but with 2 columns.

You're looking for flex justify-between. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content#space-between


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="outline outline-offset-2 outline-blue-500 rounded-lg m-4 p-2">Button 1</div>
  <div class="outline outline-offset-2 outline-blue-500 rounded-lg m-4 p-2">Button 2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




This was a perfect solution.
